# Space complexity of BFS

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search, space-complexity

Here is a code snippet from BFS implementation-

```
public static void findShortestReach(LinkedList<Integer>[] adjList,int start,int nodes)
{
    int[] level=new int[nodes];     //keeps track of distance of node in terms of number of edges
    Arrays.fill(level,-1);           //-1 signifies unreachable
    level[start-1]=0;               //distance of start from start is 0
    ArrayList<Integer> frontier=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    frontier.add(start);
    int i=1;
    while(!frontier.isEmpty())          //'nodes' times
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> next=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j:frontier)
        {   

            for(int k:adjList[j-1])
            {   
                //System.out.println(k+"hi");
                if(level[k-1]==-1)
                {
                    level[k-1]=6*i;
                    next.add(k);
                }

            }
        }
        frontier=next;
        i=i+1;
    }
    for(int l=0;l<nodes;l++)
    {    
        if(level[l]!=0)
        {
            System.out.print(level[l]+" ");


        }

    }



}
```

where 'start' is starting node and 'nodes' is number of nodes.The above algorithm is space wise inefficient as it creates ArrayList again and again inside the while loop.I am not able to convince myself in terms of complexity.

The while loop will run 'nodes' times i.e.V times. Each of these times ArrayList will be created and its size will increase as elements are added to it.Maximum number of elements it will ever store in worst case will be V-1.So the space complexity fells to be V^2. But does it capture doubling of arraylist once it is filled as that will happen many times during each iteration of while loop. How to accurately judge space complexity in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question right, your reasoning is corrrect. Note thet copying a part of the data structure does not add to the space complexity. In your case, an adjacency list (which containst at most `|V|` nodes) is copied, but this happens at most `O(|V|)` times. In total, the copying in the while loop takes `O(|V|^2)` time, which is dominated by the overall runtime complexity, which is also `O(|V|^2)`.

Comment: Can you please explain "Copying part of data structure does not add to space complexity".